# How to revert a deleted (but applied) migration in Django (MariaDB)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, database-migration

#### The Problem (Short Description)

I have a migration file deleted, but it was previously applied in the database. I want to revert the changes it has made.

#### The Problem (Long Description)

I had forked a python package and had made some changes on one of their models. I used the fork instead of the official package in my project and had my new migration applied in my database.

A couple of days ago, I replaced the fork with the official version of the package and did what I wanted to do in another way without changing the model anymore. This means, that for the same app, now one migration is missing (the migration that I created).

However, the changes that this migration made on the database are still present and the migration name is still listed on the `django_migrations` table. This has occurred weird problems, since the code and the database are not synchronized.

#### What I have tried

- I tried running `python manage.py migrate <appname> <previous_migration>` where the `appname` is the app I have problem with migrations and the `previous_migration` is the last migration the app had before I added mine.
- I tried modifying the database directly by manually reverting the changes that were made by that now deprecated migration.
- I tried deleting the table completely and letting the migration re-create it, but apparently I was wrong since Django thinks that the migrations are applied and doesn't re-apply them

#### What I want to achieve

I want to get rid of that migration, revert the changes it has made, without causing any problem. I do not care about the data that this table has (even in production), so even if the solution includes deleting the affected table, I don't mind.

However, I'm looking for a clean solution that won't complicate things too much. More likely I would love if there was something that I could do in the code and not in the database directly.

Comment: since you want to do this from code and not manually manipulating the database I suggest 1) put migration file back (switch forks) 2) migrate to the previous migration 3) then you can delete the migration file (switch forks)

Comment: @JimmyPells thanks. And if I wanted to do this through the database, what would've been the approach?

Comment: manually do what django automatically does when your run `python manage.py migrate <appname> <previous_migration>` (it really depends on what is in that migration)